# ActionScript 3.0 sound not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So having trouble making sound on keyboard press

I have the imports:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
```

I have the variables

```
private var soundDownRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("SoundDown.mp3");
private var downSound:Sound = new Sound (soundDownRequest);
```

and the event listener

```
private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

            if (evt.keyCode == 40)//ascii for down arrow 
            {
                downSound.play();

            }
    }
```

The sound folder is in the same folder as the .as, its also in the library of the fla, yet it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Thank you.

**Update:**

I got the sound to work but not using the external method I was trying to do above.

Had to do it internally.

so you need:

```
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
```

-Then you need to make sure your sound file is in your fla library.

once its in the library

-Right click > properties

-Select the Action Script Tab

-Check "export for action script"

-Give the class a name in accordance to the sound

-press ok

add this variable (your will be different):

```
private var downSound:TheDownSound = new TheDownSound();
```

downsound is the selected name of the variable, and TheDownSound is the name of the class (the one made earlier for the sound file)

then add this to where you want the sound to play:

```
var myDownSound:SoundChannel = downSound.play();
```

Do this if you cant get it working externally like me.

for a better explanation watch this guys youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZpwppe7yGs

Comment: You should post your update as an answer instead of question, because it actually answers the question. This way you'll be even eligible for some nice points in StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Aaah, good advice haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly ok if you put your `.mp3` file in the same folder as the output `.swf`, not near the class `.as` source file (because its the swf file loading the sound, so the path must be relative to it)

```
public class ASEntryPoint extends Sprite {

    private var soundDownRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("click.mp3");
    private var downSound:Sound = new Sound (soundDownRequest);

    public function ASEntryPoint() {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    }


    private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if (evt.keyCode == 40) {                
            downSound.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved it. However, how come when i give it the exact directory c:user\soOnSoForth it doesnt work? Is there no choice but to have the mp3 and swf in the same directory?

Comment: @GeorgeDziouba try escaping the absolute path or convert it(starting with `file:///` and with forward slashes `/`) or using a relative one (you can use `..` to move one folder up and use `/` slashes that don't need escaping).

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the external file, which is asynchronous operation. Then you track the loading event and if it all goes normally you can play your loaded sound.

```
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

import flash.net.URLRequest;

import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

// Keep the sound loader from being garbage collected.
var soundLoader:Sound;

function loadSound(url:String):void
{
    var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

    soundLoader = new Sound();

    // Handle the normal loading.
    soundLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

    // Handle the error cases.
    soundLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError, false, 0, true);
    soundLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError, false, 0, true);

    soundLoader.load(aRequest);
}

var audioChannel:SoundChannel;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    // Sound is available here for playback.

    audioChannel = soundLoader.play();
}

function onError(e:Event):void
{
    trace(e);
}
```

You can also handle your sound as a streaming audio, but I worked with that years ago in AS2 so I cannot help here. Still, internet suggests a link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d22.html

Comment: Hey, the problem was the mp3 and swf weren't in the same directory. Your code is better than what I was using though, so still a great answer. Its nice to have an error check.